# WPF Access Self

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This is my first day with WPF. Fun!

I currently have a WPF application that opens/returns a file with `OpenFileDialog`. I have an existing script that deconstructs and extracts that data already. What I need is to be able to access that data (I guess *bind* it to) and display it in an element in XAML. I haven't been able to figure out how to do this.

So this is my setup.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**:

```
namespace GridView
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        private GridSet<byte> _grids;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Open_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var openDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (openDialog.ShowDialog().Value)
            {
                //Populate _grids with data
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="GridView.MainWindow"
        Title="Grid View" Width="800" Height="600" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

    <DockPanel>

...
    "Open_OnClick" here
...

    <TextBox/>

    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

As you can see, the **.cs** file is simply the interaction logic for the `MainWindow`. So why on earth can't I figure out how to configure my TextBox to display data in `_grids`?

I have fiddled with `x:Name`, `x:Reference`, `Window.Resources`, `DataContext`, `Binding`, and so on, but I haven't found a guide yet that has applied to this. And it's probably because I still don't understand every facet of WPF. But what am I doing wrong here?

(I would alternatively be satisfied with a WPF tutorial that doesn't make my brain ooze out my ears.)

Comment: Change `<TextBox/>` to `<TextBox Name="myTextBox"/>`, then you can access the `TextBox` in your `MainWindow.xaml.cs` to set the text with `myTextBox.Text = "Hello World.";` And in your constructor, under `InitializeComponent();` put `this.DataContext = this;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `_grids` in your C#, but it's not added to the visual tree.

The simplest way to do this is to declare the object in the XAML (though I'm not 100% sure what a `GridSet` is - I can't find any documentation on that). So if it was a simple `Grid` you'd have:

```
<DockPanel>
    <Grid x:Name="MyGrid" />
</DockPanel>
```

By naming it you can access it in the code:

```
MyGrid.Children.Add(something);
```

To use binding you must set the `DataContext` of the window. The simplest way is to have:

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

in you constructor.

Comment: Ah, sweet! GridSet is just a way for me to interact with a bunch of grids in a clean, custom manner. The point was to be able to communicate between the two files, and you answered that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to use a button?

XAML:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="GridView.MainWindow"
    Title="Grid View" Width="800" Height="600" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

  <DockPanel>
    <Grid>
      <Button x:Name="Open" Click="Open_OnClick" />

      <TextBox x:Name="tbDisplay"/>
    </Grid>
  </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

C#

```
namespace GridView
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        private GridSet<byte> _grids;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Open_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var openDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (openDialog.ShowDialog().Value)
            {
                //Populate _grids with data
                tbDisplay.Text = "foo";
            }
        }
    }
}
```